# Galaxy SIII SCH-I535, Android 4.4.2 - High Battery Drain

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.4-kitkat

I am not quite sure where else to turn with this issue. It's been happening for about a week now. When looking at the stock battery section in Settings, I see that "Android System" is always using 35%+. It's up to 45% right now. Whereas I usually would not need to charge my phone for a few days, now, even though I still haven't changed my phone usage habits, i need to charge almost every day.

I do not have my phone rooted, or anything really special on the phone. But I am wondering why this would be so high, and how I might be able to figure out what's going on. I can provide any information that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

When I first received my SCH-I535, it performed an OTA update. I was shocked at how much battery this brand new Samsung was using. After lots of research, I reinstalled the update through my PC. You need to attach with a USB cable, let it install software from the phone onto the PC and perform a phone system update through the installed software. Basically, something got messed up with the OTA update. Reinstalling the update through the PC fixed the battery drain.

Also be aware, though, that if you're coming from a phone that didn't have an AMOLED, like an HTC, you're used to seeing the display hogging all the battery. On a Samsung, you're more likely to see the OS using more power than the display.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I do remember for some time that Display is the biggest culprit; this is fine, as I use the minimal brightness and only really give it casual use. I'm shocked you found this; I posted it nearly a near ago. But maybe I'll give this a try sometime!

EDIT: At the moment, the phoneis at 84% from 9 hours on battery; Android System is the highest at 37%, with Phone coming second at 10%. It's definitely still a problem. Only thing now is, I have the phone rooted. I don't know if this would cause problems with installing new software, though I'd probably have to root again.

Comment: Another question; do I just plug in the phone and run the installation you were talking about? Or should I factory reset again, and install fresh?

Comment: It has been a while since I did the update but I don't remember needing to factory reset before running the PC update. You may need to root again, but if you haven't tried this method before, using "towelroot" is super quick and easy.

Comment: I did use towelroot! I've got the apk somewhere. I'll definitely look into this.

Comment: Okay, new comment. I do have the driver software for "SAMSUNG Mobile USB Composite Device", as well as the "Verizon Wireless Software Utility Application for Android" installed. When I run this utility though, nothing actually happens; looking at task manager, it seems UA.exe runs, but WerFault.exe runs at the same time, and they both close a few moments later. I may have to ask a new question to get it working, since Verizon's community website (where potential answers are) is totally down.

Comment: Okay, so I cannot get the Wireless Update Utility to install properly, so I want to do it through Kies. I'm going to assume that upgrading the Firmware is essentially the same thing as updating the OS?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes unfortunately. I had a seemingly impossible to find issue on my S5, even using ultra power save. I found it to be OpenVPN - once installed and used once, the drain  started even when it wasn't in use and even after a restart of the phone. Removing OpenVPN and restarting puts battery use back to normal.